# Protected class in java

Tags: java, package, protected

This is the scenario:

Package 1 has   `Public class Machine` which has a protected variable `protected int speed=3;`

I have another package ,
Package 2 ,which has `Public class Car` which is a child of Machine class and we also have a `Public class Apple` which has the main method.

My question is :
why speed is accesible from within Car class method/constructor but not from the instance of Car class created from main method present in Appple class.

I am new in java please help ...

Answer (score 0):

The protected members of the class are only accessible to derived classes of this class, irrespective of where the class is initiated from.

You can think of public/protected/private members as not only providing required encapsulation, but sort of also dictate the levels of hierarchy to which they would be accessible.

> public-members can we accessed by all

> protected-members can be accessed by itself and its children

> private-members can be accessed only by itself

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions,

*why speed is accesible from within Car class method/constructor?*

This is because the *speed* is marked as protected, and by definition, a *protected* member is available to the class and its subclass bodies but not from *outside* of it. Since Car is subclass of *Machine*, speed is accessible from within *car*.

*but not from the instance of Car class created from main method present in Appple class*?

Here, you are trying to access the speed as public variable from outside of class/subclass body, hence is not accessible.

Please check [section 6.6.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) for more information.

Comment: Thanks but we can access protected variable from an instance like..................... ClassB Obj=new ClassB();
  Obj.k=3; ///Here,I am accessing the int k as public variable from outside of class/subclass body.

Comment: Here all classes are in same package....and int k is a protected variable of parent class of ClassB.

Comment: You cannot do that. Only way to access 'k' from outside of the class is to have public setter method for it.